# Correct way to test if Single values equal Nothing

Tags: vb.net, resharper

The following line of code gives a warning with Resharper: 'Comparison of floating point numbers with equality operator. Possible loss of precision while rounding values.'

```
Dim samples() As Single

If samples(i) = Nothing Then
    samples(i) = _mPreviousSamples(i)
End If
```

What is the best way of checking if a value is present?

Comment: probably you should look for something like `double.IsNaN(...)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the best way of checking if a value is present?

I think you have the wrong concept "`Nothing`" with regards to value types such as Single.  For value types, `Nothing` is more correctly interpreted as the *default value* for the type: in the case of a Single, 0.0.

If you want to know if a value is present with a value type, you need to first initialize the value type to hold a value that could *never* exist in this context otherwise. For primitive types such as Single, `Nothing` is rarely good enough.  In the case of Single, try using [`Single.NaN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.nan.aspx), and check the values using [`Single.IsNan()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.isnan.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know VB.NET that well, but in C# I would do something like `float? samples = null;`.

Can you declare it as a nullable like `Dim s As System.Nullable(Of Single) = Nothing`?

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim samples As System.Nullable(Of Single) = Nothing
If samples.HasValue Then
    Console.WriteLine(samples.Value)
Else
    Console.WriteLine("samples is Nothing")
End If
```

**EDIT**: Precisions:
In most cases you can use the `Nullable(Of Single)` just like a `Single`. VB automatically converts it to a `Single` where appropriate. Where not, just use the `Value` property as in the example above. Instead of `Nullable(Of Single)` you can also write `Single?` with a question mark. Instead of testing the `samples.HasValue` property you can also test `samples IsNot Nothing`.

```
Dim samples As Single? = Nothing
If samples Is Nothing Then
    Console.WriteLine("samples is Nothing")
Else
    Console.WriteLine(samples)
End If
```